# How to use axios in a Firebase Scheduled function?

Tags: json, axios, request, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a Firebase Scheduled Function that runs every 60 minutes and updates some countries. These countries data is obtained from an external API.

Here is what I have got right now:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.updateCountries = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 60 minutes').onRun((context) => {
    const URL = //build my request URL

    const axios = require('axios')
    return axios.get(url).then(response => {
        return updateCountries(response.data.results)
    }).catch(error => {
        return console.log("Request Error:", error)
    });
}

function updateCountries(results) {
    console.log("Updating data!", results)
}
```

Requesting my URL in the browser or Postman gives the following result:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "results": [
        {
            "country": "in"
        },
        //...
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is that it seems that the **updateCountries** function doesn't receive all data. Making a console log, I can see that the **results JSONArray** is not complete.

I tried **JSON.parse(results)** and it throws an unexpected token at line exception. So I am pretty sure that the axios response is not complete.

What I am missing here? How should I request my external API from a Scheduled Function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are returning directly from the Axios, this will end the cloud function.
make sure your endpoints are resolved fully before logging and returning your data which is an async result as well.